# Get when all subscriptions have ended

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm creating several subscriptions.

I need to detect when they (all) have been completed in order to perform an action.

```
private IList<IDisposable> subscriptions = new List<IDisposable>();

private void CreateSubscriptions(IEnumerable<int> integers)
{
    if (this.subscriptions.Any())
        foreach (IDisposable subscription in this.subscriptions)
            subscription.Dispose();

    this.subscriptions.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {    
        this.subscriptions.Add(
            Observable.Create<int>(
                observer =>
                {
                    foreach (int i in integers)
                        observer.OnNext(i);

                    observer.Completed();

                    return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty;
                }
            )
            .SubscribeOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .ObserveOn(this.fuasTileControl)
            .Subscribe(
                // action
            );
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm creating 50 observables that informs about next value of an `IEnumerable<int>`. This is an stuff example code.

I need to get when all subscriptions has ended (completed) in order to perform an action.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whenever you find yourself doing `return Disposable.Empty;` you're doing something wrong. Try to avoid doing that as it can break queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better options but the one I know is using the `Merge` operator. See http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html.

You can then subscribe to this observable. If you need a blocking solution you can use `Wait()` instead.

I am also interested in other solutions.

```
void Main()
{
    var sequence = CreateSubscriptions( new[] {1,5,6});

    sequence.Subscribe((i) => {}, () => { Console.WriteLine("all ready"); });

    //sequence.Wait();
    //Console.WriteLine("all ready");
}

private IList<IDisposable> subscriptions = new List<IDisposable>();

private IObservable<int> CreateSubscriptions(IEnumerable<int> integers)
{
    if (this.subscriptions.Any())
        foreach (IDisposable subscription in this.subscriptions)
            subscription.Dispose();

    this.subscriptions.Clear();
    var sequences = new List<IObservable<int>>();

    for (int ix = 0; ix < 5; ix++)
    {    
        var sequence = Observable.Create<int>(
                observer =>
                {
                    foreach (int i in integers)
                        observer.OnNext(i);

                    observer.OnCompleted();

                    return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty;
                }
            );
        sequences.Add(sequence);    
        this.subscriptions.Add(sequence.Subscribe(nr => 
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(nr); 
        }));
    }

    return Observable.Merge(sequences);
}
```

I've made some small modifications as well to make it compile.

Answer (score 1):

The slightly-pedantic, but correct answer is that this is impossible: A subscription is represented by an `IDisposable` which offers no external way to detect when it terminates (besides outright causing termination). More precisely, given the function you illustrated above to fill `IList<IDisposable> subscriptions`, there is no mechanism to act/subscribe when all those subscriptions are disposed.

There is however a way to act on a collection of observables (as represented by `IObservable`), and when those are completed.

Given either `IEnumerable<IObservable> observables` or `IObservable<IObservable> observables`, the following will work:

```
observables
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(
        item => { /*onNext handler*/ }, 
        e =>    { /*onError handler*/ }, 
        () =>   { /* onCompleted handler */});
```

You would want to put whatever action you wanted as the `onCompleted` handler.